# Meteor Cordova startup time is ridiculously slow?

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, meteor-blaze

As you can see in the gif, the startup time of the localmarket ios meteor app is ridiculously long. It took around 7 seconds normally, however once i added fastrender and fastclick, it dropped down to 4 seconds. Why is this? I noticed the Verso app loads far faster. How can I make a meteor ios app that loads faster? 4 seconds absolutely kills users, and this happens everytime the app is restarted. Any fix to this?

Btw, appcache breaks this application.

[LocalMarket](http://meteor.com/localmarket)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it myself. The problem is the launch-screen package.

1. meteor remove mobile-experience
2. meteor add fastclick
3. meteor add mobile-status-bar
4. meteor add meteorhacks:fast-render

Worked like a charm for me. Heres an article I wrote on this topic: https://medium.com/@gautham.gg/reduce-the-launch-time-of-a-meteor-mobile-app-e2f009951011#.8uovmstb5

Answer (score 0):

Change your splash screen time from AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0]; //5 is the time in second for splash screen
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this within your layout `onRendered`

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}
```